# Button in partialview stops working after search

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Layout page and a PartialView.

I have a search-button on the layout page and an update-button in a table in the partial view.

Once I click the search-button the update-button stops working. It works fine until I search. I'm guessing it has to do with the forms and actionresult but I can't get it to work. The actionresult is never reached - "nothing" happens.

[image: Image of the problem]

**Controller - RegisterTruckUser**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterTruckUser(string registerName, string registerPassword, string employeeNumber, string userTeam)
        {
            var model = new RegisterModel
            {
                UserList = db.SearchTruckUsers(""),
                UserTeamList = GetUserTeamList(),
                TriggerOnLoad = true
            };

            //If the Save button is clicked the user is updated
            if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("btnupdateuser"))
            {
                if (!Request["btnupdateuser"].IsEmpty())
                {
                    Name = Request.Form["item.Name"];
                    password = Request["item.Password"];
                    EmployeeNumber = Request["item.EmployeeNumber"];
                    Userteam = Request["item.UserTeam"];

                    db.UpdateTruckUser(Name, password, EmployeeNumber, Userteam);
                    model.UserList = db.SearchTruckUsers("");
                    return PartialView(model);
                }
            }
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View(model);
            }
            model.TriggerOnLoadMessage = ErrorMessage;
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Controller - SearchPartialView**

```
[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult SearchPartialView(string searchUserString)
        {
            if (Session["myID"] == null)
            {
                ExpireSession();
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                RedirectToLogin();

            if (searchUserString.Any(char.IsDigit))
            {
                var model1 = new RegisterModel
                {
                    TriggerOnLoad = false,
                    UserList = db.SearchTruckUsersEmpNum(searchUserString),
                    UserTeamList = GetUserTeamList()
                };
                return PartialView("_RegisterTruckUserPartialView", model1);
            }

            var model = new RegisterModel
            {
                TriggerOnLoad = false,
                UserList = db.SearchTruckUsers(searchUserString),
                UserTeamList = GetUserTeamList()
            };
            return PartialView("_RegisterTruckUserPartialView", model);
        }
```

**RegisterLayout**

```
@model Name.Models.RegisterModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Register</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
</head>

<body>
    @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
    @RenderBody()
    <div class="center" id="top">

                    <div id="search" class="active">
                        <h1>Manage users</h1>

                        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchPartialView", "Register", null,
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "divUsers",
            }, new
            {
                id = "usertable"
            }))
                        {

                            @Html.TextBox("SearchUserString", null, new { @class = "responsivetextbox", @placeholder = "Search username or employment number" })
                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" class="standardbutton logsearch" name="submit" value="Search" />
                            </p>
                        }
                        <div id="divUsers">
                            @{Html.RenderPartial("_RegisterTruckUserPartialView");}
                        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml")
</body>
</html>
```

**PartialView (table)**

```
<table class="centeredTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Employment Number</th>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.UserList)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <tr id="usertabletr1">
                    <td id="usertabletd1">
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@name = "test1", @style = "border: 0px none;"}})
                    </td>
                    <td id="usertabletd1">
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Password, new {htmlAttributes = new {@name = "registerPassword", @type = "password", @style = "border: 0px none; "}})
                    </td>
                    <td id="usertabletd1">
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeNumber, new {htmlAttributes = new {@name = "employeeNumber", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "border: 0px none; background: white;"}})
                    </td>
                    <td id="usertabletd1">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.UserTeam, Model.UserTeamList, item.UserTeam, new {htmlAttributes = new {@name = "Team", @style = "border: 0px none;"}})
                    </td>
                    <td id="usertabletd1">
                            <input class="standardbutton adddefaultvaluesubmit" type="image" src="~/Pictures/saveicon.ico" alt="Save" value="Save" name="btnupdateuser"/>
                        <input class="standardbutton adddefaultvaluesubmit" type="image" src="~/Pictures/trashcanicon.ico" alt="Delete" value="Delete" name="btndeleteuser"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Getting any error in a console?

Comment: @Div No, nothing.

Comment: Before clicking the search button, was it working?

Comment: @RichaGarg OP has already mentioned in the question *It works fine until I search*

Comment: @Div Updated the question with the search-controller which returns the partialview, if that helps.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://msprogrammer.serviciipeweb.ro/2011/12/05/jquery-ajax-request-and-mvcdetailed/

Comment: Are you using any javascript/ajax to submit the forms in the table?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Only Ajax.BeginForm, if I understand it correctly

Comment: Specify the action and controller names - `@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterTruckUser", "yourControllerName"))`

Comment: You also have a problem because an `<input type="image" .. />` will not submit its value

Comment: @StephenMuecke I specified the action and controller name but still have the same problem. Also changed the input type to submit, but still nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean _nothing happens_? Are you hitting the `RegisterTruckUser()` method (sorry if this sounds harsh, but there is so much nonsense code in the controller and view that nothing could work if it did hit the method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think that he means that the save button works perfectly and enters the right actionresult in the controller before a search, which uses the same partialview as after the search. But after searching literally nothing happens. There's nothing in the console, no breakpoint in the entire controller is hit. As if it no longer registers it as a button. But the button looks the same when you look at it in the browser (Press F12 in Google Chrome).

Comment: @Danieboy, The code in the `RegisterTruckUser()` does nothing whatsoever (every parameter in the signature will be `null` and the values declared in the `if` block will always be `null` and nothing could ever be saved) - it cannot possibly work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are probably correct. Which is confusing if it works before searching. On a sidenote... Are you allowed to for-each loop a form like that?

Comment: @Danieboy Can you? - yes. Should you? Absolutely NOT

Comment: @StephenMuecke RegisterTruckuser works the first time, but is not hit after search. 
How should the foreach be done? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see how you can claim it 'works'. You have 4 parameters in the method signature and all of them will be null (you do not have any form controls with `name` attributes that match the parameter names - and fortunately your `new { @name = ... }` does nothing) but you never use those values anyway. If if you could enter your `if` blocks, the values for `Name`, `password` etc will also be `null` since `Request.Form` will never contain values for `item.Name`, `item.Password` etc. (inspect the html your generating - in particular the `name` attributes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Yes the 4 paramters are null in this case, but the Request.Form contains the correct values. If I load the page and update the name in the table, click the save image, the breakpoint hits in the correct actionResult and I get the correct item.name, item.password, item.employeenumber and item.userteam. But if I search first, the actionresult never  hits when I click the save image, and I dont see anything new in the console.

Answer (score 1):

In your partial view it should look something like this.

```
<input type="button" value="Confirm team change" class="btnConfirm"/>
```

And then you add this to your "main" layout.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnConfirm', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("RegisterTruckUser", "Register")',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(result){
        //do something
    }
 });
});
```